# How to solve "Chunked body did not terminate properly with 0-sized chunk."?

Tags: asp.net, iis, rss

I have an RSS feed. When I browse to the feed with Fiddler Web Debugger open, Fiddler throws this error at me:

```
Chunked body did not terminate properly with 0-sized chunk.
```

The response from the server that triggered the error looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 22 Jan 2013 21:00:49 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 30985

<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
  ... etc
```

The owner of the RSS is reporting problems when trying to submit the site to RSS aggregators.

I tried to validate the rss here: http://validator.w3.org/appc/. The response was this:

```
IncompleteRead(30985 bytes read) (IncompleteRead; misconfigured server?)
```

However, if I browse to the rss and copy past the code into this validator: http://validator.w3.org/appc/#validate_by_input, then everything validates correctly.

How do I correct this? This is a C# ASP.NET webforms project running on .NET 3.5 in IIS6.

### Update

It appears that I was using Fiddler incorrectly. After unchcking the Decode option, here is the server response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 22 Jan 2013 21:22:03 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

7909
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
   ... etc
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data you posted above is not what the server sent. The response from the server contained a HTTP Header **Transfer-Encoding: chunked** but your data was not properly in the HTTP-chunked encoding format.

Please update your question with the actual data, as captured by Fiddler, making sure the **Decode** option in Fiddler's toolbar is **NOT** checked.

(As to the root cause of the problem, did you mistakenly call Response.Close()? See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/07/16/content-length-and-transfer-encoding-validation-in-ie10-download-manager-couldnt-be-downloaded-retry-cancel.aspx) for an explanation of why that's the incorrect way to complete a HTTP response.)

Comment: I would have expected to see the Transfer-encoding: chunked there as well. However, there was no such property in the server response as shown above. The server response from above was taken from Fiddler (the Raw tab).

Comment: Wait a minute... I had the Decode option selected... I updated the question.

Comment: Now, look at the very bottom of the response. It's supposed to end with 0\r\n\r\n, and it doesn't. You didn't answer whether you call Response.Close() in your code?

Comment: I called Response.Close(). I replaced it with Response.End() instead. It is now working. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: A side effect I observed tracking a similar case: the browser could not download a server-generated file due to "chunked" issue, but when connecting through fiddler, the browser WAS able to download the affected file.